# How to style the React google map marker using the given image file

Tags: css, reactjs

Now I am using React-google-map component and want to change the marker to my own image. At this moment, I can't change the size of the marker using CSS.
I've tried as follows:

```
var image = {
    url: '../images/icons/yellow.png',
    size: 10
};

return (
    <Marker 
        position={location}
        icon={image}
        onClick={this.handleMarkerClick.bind(this, marker)}
    />
    );
```

If you know the solution, please kindly let me know.

Thanks for your help in advance.

Comment: A simple googling will result in this Github issue (https://github.com/tomchentw/react-google-maps/issues/486) which provides a clear answer. If you'd bother searching your question, you'd know. It's the first result. Besides that, you can't just guess attributes and hope they will work - this is a React library that was coded with certain attributes in mind.

Answer (score 3):

You have to pass a url of the image, like:  icon={url}

Example:

```
return (
    <Marker 
    position={location}
    icon={"http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/icons/blue.png"}
    />
);
```

For more info: [github.com/tomchentw/react-google-maps/issues/486](http://github.com/tomchentw/react-google-maps/issues/486)